# How can the documentation for Java's File.getAbsoluteFile() refer to "this" without context?

Tags: java

In the Java 1.6 documentation, the keyword "this" is employed without a context in the description of File.getAbsoluteFile().  See the "equivalent to" sentence.  Fortunately, the getAbsolutePath() token is a link to documentation on a method of object File, so it is possible to infer what is meant by "this".  My question: Is following the link necessary to understand the context or is this an example of employing the "this" keyword in a way with which I am not familiar?

**getAbsoluteFile**

public File getAbsoluteFile()
Returns the absolute form of this abstract pathname. 
Equivalent to new File(this.getAbsolutePath()).

Returns:
The absolute abstract pathname denoting the same file 
or directory as this abstract pathname

Throws:
SecurityException - If a required system property value 
cannot be accessed.

Since: 1.2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that `new File(this.getAbsolutePath())` should not be interpreted as being equivalent to **invoking** getAbsoluteFile().  Rather the documentation means that the implementation of getAbsoluteFile() is equivalent to `return new File(this.getAbsolutePath())`.

Answer (score 0):

"this" is simply the File object you call the getAbsoluteFile() on. You have a File object that represents a file by its name, and you can make a new File object that represents the same file name, but by its absolute file path

Comment: "this" is the File object only if I am inheriting from File.  Otherwise, it's not "this".

Answer (score 0):

'this' has the same meaning here that it has in the Java language itself. It refers to the instance of File on which the method is invoked. No 'context' or 'inference' required.